# Reading information from text file in C

Tags: c, file, input

I'm new to C; please try to help me as much as you can.
I'm getting as arguments to `main()` pointers to files,
so in a for loop I `fopen()` them and want to send them to a function that will
read the text info inside them and put it in char variables.

Here is an example file:

```
#station name
Station Name : A1
#octan of fuel 6.54 full service price 6.40 self service
Octan95,6.54,6.40
Octan98,8.30,8.15
#carNum,Octan,numOfLiters,Kind of service
22-334-55,95,31.3,FullService
22-334-55,95,31.3,SelfService
11-444-77,95,12,FullService
11-444-77,95,44.1,FullService
11-444-77,95,11.22,SelfService
```

The text has fields separated with commas, and I need the information between those commas to be added to vars.
What will be the best way or function to read these text files?
Also should I expect `'\n'` after each line or will it stream as one big `char[]` without the new line character?

Comment: What have you written?  What data structures are you planning to use?  How variable are the formats (will other files have different sets of columns, or are the sets of columns all fixed)?  What do you need to do after the data is read in?

Comment: To answer your last question, you should expect a newline after each line - assuming you use `fgets()` to read the file in lines.

Answer (score 0):

read file line by line
use strtok function to get everything in between commas

Comment: strtok switch over empty comma-delimited fields

Answer (score 0):

read file line by line and use sscanf with return-value to get everything in between commas

Answer (score 0):

Some 200 lines of code later...and using a slightly modified version of your data file (note that the second header line in the original is missing all the commas):

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/*
** Example data:
**
** #station name
** Station Name : A1
** #octan of fuel,full service price,self service price
** Octan95,6.54,6.40
** Octan98,8.30,8.15
** #carNum,Octan,numOfLiters,Kind of service
** 22-334-55,95,31.3,FullService
** 22-334-55,95,31.3,SelfService
** 11-444-77,95,12,FullService
** 11-444-77,95,44.1,FullService
** 11-444-77,95,11.22,SelfService
**
** - Header lines are followed by one or more data lines
** - Number of fields in header matches number of fields in each data line
** - Commas separate fields and do not appear within fields (not full CSV)
*/

/* A Line structure holds the fields for one line */
typedef struct Line
{
    size_t   num_fields;
    char   **fields;
} Line;

/* A Section structure holds the header line and the set of data lines */
typedef struct Section
{
    size_t  num_rows;
    size_t  num_cols;
    Line    header;
    Line   *lines;  /* Array of lines - num_rows entries in array */
} Section;

/* An Info structure holds all the sections for a single file */
typedef struct Info
{
    size_t   num_sections;
    Section *sections;
} Info;

static void err_exit(const char *format, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    vfprintf(stderr, format, args);
    va_end(args);
    exit(1);
}

static void *xrealloc(void *old_data, size_t nbytes)
{
    void *new_data = realloc(old_data, nbytes);
    if (new_data == 0)
        err_exit("Out of memory!\n");
    return new_data;
}

static void *xmalloc(size_t nbytes)
{
    void *new_data = malloc(nbytes);
    if (new_data == 0)
        err_exit("Out of memory!\n");
    return new_data;
}

/* Duplicate a string of given length (excluding NUL) */
static char *xstrndup(const char *str, size_t len)
{
    char *new_data = xmalloc(len+1);
    memmove(new_data, str, len);
    new_data[len] = '\0';
    return new_data;
}

static void dump_line(FILE *fp, const Line * const line)
{
    size_t i;
    const char *pad = "";
    for (i = 0; i < line->num_fields; i++)
    {
        fprintf(fp, "%s%*s", pad, 1, line->fields[i]);
        pad = "  ";
    }
    fputc('\n', fp);
}

static void dump_section(FILE *fp, const char *tag, const Section * const section)
{
    if (tag != 0)
        fprintf(fp, "Dump Section: %s\n", tag);
    fprintf(fp, "Number of columns: %zd\n", section->num_cols);
    fprintf(fp, "Number of lines:   %zd\n", section->num_rows);
    dump_line(fp, &section->header);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < section->num_rows; i++)
        dump_line(fp, &section->lines[i]);
}

static void dump_info(FILE *fp, const char *tag, const Info * const info)
{
    size_t i;

    fprintf(fp, "Dump Information: %s\n", tag);
    fprintf(fp, "Number of sections: %zd\n", info->num_sections);
    for (i = 0; i < info->num_sections; i++)
    {
        char title[20];
        snprintf(title, sizeof(title), "%d", i+1);
        dump_section(fp, title, &info->sections[i]);
    }
    fprintf(fp, "End of Information Dump\n");
}

static int num_fields(const char *buffer)
{
    size_t posn = 0;
    size_t next;
    int count = 0;
    while ((next = strcspn(buffer + posn, ",\n")) > 0)
    {
        count++;
        if (buffer[posn+next] == '\n')
            break;
        posn += next + 1;
    }
    return count;
}

static void set_line(Line *line, int nfields, const char *buffer)
{
    size_t posn = 0;
    line->num_fields = nfields;
    line->fields = xmalloc(nfields * sizeof(*line->fields));
    for (int i = 0; i < nfields; i++)
    {
        size_t next = strcspn(buffer+posn, ",\n");
        line->fields[i] = xstrndup(buffer+posn, next);
        if (buffer[posn+next] == '\n')
        {
            if (i != nfields - 1)
                err_exit("Internal error: field count mismatch\n");
            break;
        }
        posn += next + 1;
    }
}

static int add_section(Info *info, char *buffer)
{
    int nfields = num_fields(buffer);
    int nsections = info->num_sections + 1;
    info->sections = xrealloc(info->sections, nsections * sizeof(*info->sections));
    info->num_sections = nsections;
    Section *new_section = &info->sections[nsections-1];
    new_section->num_cols = nfields;
    new_section->num_rows = 0;
    set_line(&new_section->header, nfields, buffer);
    new_section->lines = 0;
    return nfields;
}

/* Beware - very compact code! */
static void add_line_to_section(Section *section, const char *buffer, int nfields)
{
    section->lines = xrealloc(section->lines, (section->num_rows + 1) * sizeof(*section->lines));
    set_line(&section->lines[section->num_rows++], nfields, buffer);
}

static int peek(FILE *fp)
{
    int c;
    if ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF)
        ungetc(c, fp);
    return c;
}

static void read_info(FILE *fp, Info *info)
{
    char buffer[1024];
    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp) != 0)
    {
        if (*buffer != '#')
            err_exit("Format error: expected line beginning '#' (got '%.*s')\n",
                     10, buffer);
        int nfields = add_section(info, buffer+1);
        int c;
        Section *cursect = &info->sections[info->num_sections-1];
        while ((c = peek(fp)) != EOF && c != '#')
        {
            if (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp) != 0)
            {
                int lfields = num_fields(buffer);
                if (lfields != nfields)
                    err_exit("Mismatch in number of fields (got %d, wanted %) at '%*s'\n",
                             lfields, nfields, 20, buffer);
                add_line_to_section(cursect, buffer, nfields);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;
    Info info = { 0, 0 };

    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        FILE *fp;
        if ((fp = fopen(argv[i], "r")) != 0)
        {
            read_info(fp, &info);
            dump_info(stdout, "After loop", &info);
        }
        else
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file %s (%s)\n", argv[i], strerror(errno));
    }
    dump_info(stdout, "End of main loop", &info);
    return 0;
}
```

The code is not optimal in most senses - it allocates far too many small bits of memory.  I also got lazy and didn't write the code to free the memory.  I don't think it would be a good idea to hand this in as your code, though.